# entity framework / linq query construction

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following tables:

**Project:**

```
Id
SettlementId
...
```

**Settlement**

```
Id
Name
AreaId
```

**Area**

```
Id
Name
...
```

I need to get all settlements that belong to a particular area (i get the areaId from the selected dropdownlist) that are not part of any project.

So far this is my query:

```
var settlements = (from s in entities.Settlements
                  where s.AreaId == selectedAreaId
                  select s).toList();
```

Am not entirely sure how to filter out the settlements that are already part of an existing project.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try?

```
where s.Projects.Count() == 0
```

Comment: hah that worked.. I'm new to C# and I never knew about the fact that I get an ICollection property after i declare a 1 -> * rel. Thanks heaps! Will accept your answer as correct after 5 mins

Comment: Even better, ``!s.Projects.Any()``; ``Count`` always iterates the collection, but ``Any`` just returns true if it finds something. It's a minor improvement, but there's no reason not to do it.